# Run a Ruby program in mac terminal

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, operating-system

i'm new to programming and a couple of days ago i started a ruby course on codecademy. i found that instead of an ide, for ruby is usually used Sublime Text. the problem is that i can't run a simple program from the terminal of the mac by typing " ruby test.rb " (test is the name of the script). in another question in here said that it was enough, but not in my case. what can i do to run it ? here's the code anyway:)

```
def main
    print "Enter yout name: "
    input = gets.chomp
end 
main
```

it's really simple but i wanted to write down something to test it first
plus i followed the first paragraph (installing) and the "Running ruby code" part of this ruby guide:
https://launchschool.com/books/ruby/read/preparations
what should i do? thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an error message or something else we can get information from?

Comment: ruby: No such file or directory -- test.rb (LoadError)

Comment: this is the error i get. asking the question i missed type the name of the script: it is test.rb not .tb

Comment: Then edit it in your question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in the folder where the test file is? The steps to run a ruby program from terminal are:

1. Navigate to folder where your ruby file is by typing `cd foldername` until you've drilled down to where the file is. If you are unsure what is in the current folder, type `ls` to list all files & folders.
2. When you've gone into the proper folder, type `ls` again and you should see `test.rb`. The extension of the file should be .rb not .tb. Don't know if that's a type or not.
3. Type `ruby test.rb` and your program should work.  I mimicked your code and it runs on my Mac terminal.

Comment: That seems to be working perfectly! thank you so much for your help, this was the first time using the terminal for me